# Can I check available storage in the Device on Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms

I am trying to make an app that requires that I frequently send recorded data to a firebase. When network goes out or battery is about to die, I am saving all of the data that wasn't stored into firebase locally. However, to do this I require about 20 MB of data (my data is pretty big). That being said, I want to find a way to check the available storage (and the battery if possible) to give the user a warning. Is this possible using Xamarin Forms? Also, is there a way that I can make this solution universal (i.e. I don't need a separate piece of code for iOS vs. Android)? (I am new to Xamarin and C#)

Comment: Check the amount of free space on your drive since you are writing to a file.

Comment: What do you mean by this? I am trying to find the available space on the device running the app.

Comment: @SriramA. have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following code to check the free size of a device:

For iOS:

```
NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetFileSystemAttributes (Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)).FreeSize;
```

For Android:

```
var freeExternalStorage = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.UsableSpace;
```

There is no universal option, but you can wrap it an interface like so and implement it on each project:

```
public interface IStorage
{
    double GetRemainingStorage();
}
```

It would be great if a feature like this could be added in Xamarin.Essentials - there was a request on GitHub but it never really made it.

If there are any issues with the code - please tell me.

Hope this helped,

**Instructions**
Create an interface in your **shared project** titled `IStorage`.

In your Android project create a class titled `AndroidStorageManager` (you can name it however you would like). Make it so it extends `IStorage`. The method `GetRemainingStorage()` should be of return type `double`.

[image]

```
 public class AndroidStorageManager : IStorage
    {
        public double GetRemainingStorage()
        {
            var freeExternalStorage = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.UsableSpace;

            return freeExternalStorage;
        }
    }
```

**For iOS**
Create a class in your iOS project titled `iOSStorageManager` which extends `IStorage`:

```
 public class iOSStorageManager : IStorage
    {
        public double GetRemainingStorage()
        {
            return NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetFileSystemAttributes(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)).FreeSize;
        }
    }
```

In your Android implementation - add the following code above the namespace:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(
          typeof(AndroidStorageManager))]
```

For iOS:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(
          typeof(iOSStorageManager))]
```

To get the storage:

```
 IStorage storageManager = DependencyService.Get<IStorage>();
            double remaining = storageManager.GetRemainingStorage();
```

Hope this clarified things.

Comment: Check my revised answer. @SriramA. - tell me if it works or not