# Xamarin Forms w/ Mobile Blazor Bindings - How to specify dependency injection in Blazor app for class defined in Android / iOS projects

Tags: xamarin.forms, blazor

Within my Blazor app, I am trying to determine the amount of available storage of the Android or iOS device.

I have found an answer here that is relevant:

[Can I check available storage in the Device on Xamarin Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65440467/can-i-check-available-storage-in-the-device-on-xamarin-forms)

As per the accepted answer, I have implemented the following:

#### Defined the Interface in the Blazor project

```
public interface IStorage
{
    double GetRemainingStorage();
}
```

#### Created a class in the Android project

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(AndroidStorageManager))]

namespace MyApp.Android
{
    public class AndroidStorageManager : IStorage
    {
        public double GetRemainingStorage()
        {
            var freeSpace = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.UsableSpace;

            return freeSpace;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Created a class in the iOS project

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(iOSStorageManager))]

namespace MyApp.iOS
{
    public class iOSStorageManager : IStorage
    {
        public double GetRemainingStorage()
        {
            var freeSpace = NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetFileSystemAttributes(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)).FreeSize;

            return freeSpace;
        }
    }
}
```

### The Issue

Despite the definition of the dependencies with the `[assembly:` attribute, when my Blazor app tries to inject an instance of IStorage, it throws an exception:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'IStorage' ...

Of course, I'm not able to define the dependency injection for IService in the Blazor app on startup, since the AndroidStorageManager and iOSStorageManager are defined in the device-specific projects which are already referencing the Blazor app.

I suspect I need some other way of defining the DI for IService in the Android and iOS apps, but can't see how to do it.

Can anyone offer any advice?

Comment: please read the linked answer again - the `[assembly...]` attribute goes above the `namespace` declaration in the class file, NOT in `AssemblyInfo.cs`

Comment: Thank you.  You are correct; my bad. I've modified my code, and the question, accordingly.  But I'm still getting the same result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have found a workaround for my immediate issue, but I'm sure there must be a more elegant solution.

The exception was being generated when trying to inject an instance of the class associated with the IStorage interface.

```
public class MyManager {

    private IStorage _storage;

    public MyManager(IStorage storage) {
        _storage = storage;
    }

    ...
}
```

Rather then relying on the Blazor DI to resolve this dependency, I was able to use Xamarin.Forms DI to inject an instance manually, as follows:

```
public class MyManager {

    private IStorage _storage;

    public MyManager() {
        _storage = DependencyService.Get<IStorage>();
    }

    ...
}
```

I'm assuming that my original code wasn't working because Xamarin.Forms and Blazor are not sharing the same DI container.  I'm not sure.

I'd be interested in anyone that can suggest a more elegant solution.